# Inclusion-exclusion formula for the Liouville Lambda function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, inclusion-exclusion, liouville-function

The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \lambda (k)}{n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}}=0$$
according to "The Riemann Hypothesis: A Resource for the Afficionado and Virtuoso Alike" by Peter Borwein, at page 6.
where:
$$L(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \lambda (k)$$
Is the following inclusion-exclusion formula for the partial sums of the Liouville lambda function correct?
$$L(n) = \underbrace{\underset {a^2\leq n} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}} 1 - \underset {a^2 b\leq n} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}\sum_ {b\geq 2}} 1 + \underset {a^2 bc\leq n} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}\sum_ {b\geq 2}\sum_ {c\geq 2}} 1 - \underset {a^2 bcd\leq n} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}\sum_ {b\geq 2}\sum_ {c\geq 2}\sum_ {d\geq 2}} 1 + \cdots}_{\text{number of alternating sums} > \frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}}$$

Comment: See Mathematica code at the end of: https://pastebin.com/LUG5i3jX

Comment: Have I misunderstood what inclusion-exclusion means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this formula is correct.  For one way to see this, start by changing all the occurrences of "$\le n$" in the formula to "$=n$".  Call the result $F(n)$.  Then, for correctness, you need $F(n)$ to equal the value $\lambda(n)$ of the Liouville lambda function at $n$.  Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(n)&=&\underset {a^2= n} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}} 1 - \underset {a^2 b=n} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}\sum_ {b\geq 2}} 1 + \underset {a^2 bc=n} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}\sum_ {b\geq 2}\sum_ {c\geq 2}} 1 - \cdots \\
&=& \underset {a^2= n} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}} 1 -\sum_{b\ge 2} \left( \underset {a^2 = n/b} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}} 1 - \underset {a^2 c=n/b} {\sum_ {a\geq 1}\sum_ {c\geq 2}} 1 + \cdots \right) \\
&=& [\hbox{$n$ is a square}] - \sum_{b\ge 2,\ b|n} F(n/b),
\end{eqnarray*}
since the sum in the parentheses will vanish unless $n/b$ is an integer.  So
$$
\sum_{d|n} F(d) = \sum_{b|n} F(n/b)=[\hbox{$n$ is a square}]
$$
and using the Möbius inversion formula gives
$$
F(n)=\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) [\hbox{$n/d$ is a square}].
$$
Since $\mu(d)$ vanishes unless $d$ is squarefree, and any positive integer can be written uniquely as a product of a squarefree positive integer and a square positive integer, exactly one of the terms in this sum is nonzero, and by the definition of the Liouville lambda function, it will equal $\lambda(n)$.  So $F(n)=\lambda(n)$, which is what you want.

Comment: I'm glad to see you are using the Iverson bracket, I think is a beautiful and very useful notation that should be more popular. Unfortunately that's not the case, so I suggest you include the definition of the notation in your answer.